# Flask Error: If something fails in the flask backend, how does the error propagate to the front end?

Tags: api, rest, flask

Consider a simple application where a user fills a form to divide two numbers, in the routes the form data is proceeded [made into float] and then passed as parameters to a python script's function that has the division logic.

The logic fails due to division by 0 is handled as a custom message in the terminal. How does one send this custom message back to the front end UI along with a 500 error message? Trying to make a restful flask app here.

So far I can abort and show a custom message but not the one that propagated from the backend. Also looked into custom error handling but I want to writer of the external python script to be able to write the custom message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Flask errorhandler(errorcode) to manage your errors and display those on the frontend.

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def code_500(error):
    return render_template("errors/500.html", error=error), 500
```

You can put whatever else you want in the html template.
You can also call the `code_500(error)` func directly.

Same principle applies for any other HTTP error code if you want to customize the page and the message (401, 403, 404, etc...).

If you're inside a blueprint, you can use `app_errorhandler` instead.

Comment: i understand this approach, but I want the contents of the 500.html to be the error message that someone else wrote. So if i import custom_package and execute custom_package.custom_function [that has its own specific error message] like so try : custom_package.custom_function(x,y) except : return the developer written message

Comment: You could do a return code_500(error) and pass your error message as the error, then in the 500.html, display the error message with jinja2 {{ error }}

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `abort()` function. From the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/errorpages/#returning-api-errors-as-json):

> When using Flask for web APIs, you can use the same techniques as above to return JSON responses to API errors. abort() is called with a description parameter. The errorhandler() will use that as the JSON error message, and set the status code to 404.

You could implement it like this

```py
@app.route("/div")
def divide():
    x, y = request.form['x'], request.form['y']

    try:
        result = x / y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        abort(400, description="Your message here")
    else:
        # Proper response
```

From there, the important step is properly catching that message on your frontend.

Comment: in this case, incase the result = x /y was a logic written in a separate package, and that package threw an error how would i show that? the developer of that package could have written something like hey you cant do this and thats the message I want to show